# A string that contains aabb, does this work?

Tags: finite-automata

Can you verify this like please bro please tell me the answer to my question
[image]

Comment: No. Your machine accepts ababab. Well, actually it works if the aabb don't have to be together. But usually this question means they have to be all together in a row, so ababab doesn't count.

Answer (score 1):

Have 5 states `S`, `Sa`, `Saa`, `Saab`, `Saabb`. Move to a state `Sxxx` after you parsed the first characters `xxx` of `aabb`, except you stay in the accepting state `Saabb` no matter what the input once you reached it.

```
S:     a->Sa,    b->S.
Sa:    a->Saa,   b->Sa.
Saa:   a->Saa,   b->Saab.
Saab:  a->Saab,  b->Saabb.
Saabb: a->Saabb, b->Saabb.
```

Answer (score -2):

This automaton only accepts strings that START with aabb.  You also need to accept strings such as baabb, bababaabbabab, aabaabb, etc.

Comment: It accepts also $baabb$, $bbaabb$ etc. The actual problem is it accepts non-consecutive $aabb$